# adding logo within jquery mmenu

Tags: mmenu

What a great responsive menu might I first of all say. I'd like to take this a little further by adding a small logo into the slide out.

At the moment I'm doing this by firstly adding a good deal of padding to this element:

```
.mm-menu > .mm-list {padding:160px 0 0 0;}
```

Then I'm using the menu div created I'm inserting with jquery a div which holds the logo as a background image:

```
$("#mobile").prepend("<div class='logo'></div>");
```

CSS for this:

```
#mobile .logo {width:80%; height:124px; max-height:124px; z-index:1000; position:absolute; top:10px; left:50%; margin-left:-40%; background:url(../Images/mob_logo_slide.png) top center no-repeat;}
```

This all looks great until you have a menu that is a little longer than the users screen, so then when you scroll the first menu items such as Home, About Us ect all overlay onto the jQuery inserted logo.

I need a way of making the 160 padding being the top of the menu so it does not scroll over it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this? I want a logo above the menu but it just slides out of view when a menu item is clicked.

Comment: Hi Cristina, I kind of did but have scrapped the idea as if you were to add a logo to the top, then view the menu on a mobile in landscape mode for instance the user would have to scroll to see any of the menu really, we felt in the end it should just be a menu after all. To do it though we had to add lots of padding to the top of the ul then insert using a jQuery append a div with the css adding the logo png as the background.